# feature scaling in online learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, regularization, online-algorithms

Let's take Logistic Regression as an example, typically we should do feature scaling before applying `l1` or `l2` regularizations.

When do batch learning, feature scaling could be easily done, but how could we do this in online learning scenario, since data points come in a stream fashion and no way to know the `mean` and `std` of the data.

By *[feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling)*, I mean all the features should be transformed such that they have roughly the same scale, and this is typically done by *mean-centering* and *divided by the standard deviation* of the feature.

Questions

1) AFAIK, we could buffer a few of recent data points, say data received within an hour, and compute the `mean` and `std`, then do feature scaling for later data. Could this approach work well?

2) `FTRL` algorithm, I didn't see how it does feature scaling in the paper, but it applies **per-coordinate (i.e. per feature)** learning rate, is this the way it deals with features with different scales?

Comment: @ttnphns, I updated with the definition of *feature scaling*, and also removed optimal-scaling (which is not quite pertinent here, sorry about that).

Comment: there are dynamic averaging as well, so you don't need to "hold" data to estimate its mean and variance.  You can also look at row-to-row changes in means or variance to adjust whether learning needs to be re-started.  What are you trying to do, in particular, here?  What motivates the question, because specific needs can inform a better answer.

Comment: @EngrStudent, I just wondered how those online learning algorithms deal with *scale* issue, since if we apply regularization, *features' scale* need to be dealt properly.